# Image assest in Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I just installed Android Studio 1.0.2, and when I want to create a new project I can't find Icon Editor. There was this feature in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and also in Android Studio tutorials. Should I install something that I missed?

I found this way, but it didn't work for me (I did this, but nothing happened):

1. Open Search Everywhere by Double Shift at Android Studio
2. Type image asset + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I don't recall an icon editor ever being in Android Studio. There is the icon set wizard, though.

Comment: Android studio gives you an option to make a new project in File>New Project, if you would like to have a icon for that then right click on toolbar it will give you options to customize your toolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about what Icon Editor you are talking about. When you have setup your project, and you want to import an image and possible edit it, there is this editor

[image: image editor path]

[image]

Comment: I had worked with Eclipse for a short while, and, that wizard appeared whenever a new project was started. When I switched to Android Studio, it seemed to not exist. I eventually stumbled upon it, just where you've noted.